# Shifting cells to the right

Tags: excel, vba

I am basically trying reformat a terribly laid out report. You can see in the linked picture. I have data in column A that is either a number, date, or the word "outside." If in any given row column A has the word "outside," then I want to move the value in column E to column N and value in column F to column O in the row above. If in any given row column A is blank, then I want to delete that entire row. If in any given row column A is a date, then move column D to column B and column E to Column C in the row below. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

[image: example spreadsheet]

Comment: Yes it's possible...

Comment: If vba is not a language you like working in, for this type of formatting work you can export this spreadsheet to a csv file and then perform formatting using a different language.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested so make sure to try this on a copy and not the original :)

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Help()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update
Dim i As Long, DeleteMe As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If IsDate(ws.Range("A" & i)) Then
            ws.Range("B" & i + 1).Value = ws.Range("D" & i).Value
            ws.Range("E" & i + 1).Value = ws.Range("C" & i).Value
            ws.Range("D" & i).ClearContents
            ws.Range("C" & i).ClearContents
        ElseIf ws.Range("A" & i) = "output" Then
            ws.Range("N" & i - 1).Value = ws.Range("E" & i).Value
            ws.Range("O" & i - 1).Value = ws.Range("F" & i).Value
            ws.Range("E" & i).ClearContents
            ws.Range("F" & i).ClearContents
        ElseIf ws.Range("A" & i) = "" Then
            If DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteMe = ws.Range("A" & i)
            Else
                Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, ws.Range("A" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. That mostly worked, but the  ws.Range("D" & i).ClearContents
            ws.Range("C" & i).ClearContents then somehow went back and deleted what had just been moved.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Was working on a solution.  Thanks again